# Remote Access issue with MySQL

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I have done the following things to connect to MySQL server.

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = xx.xx.xx.xx
```

and did

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO user-name@'xx.xx.xx.xx' IDENTIFIED BY '******';
```

I could be able to telnet into 3306 port from the remote machine. But my rake task could not able to connect through.

What might be the issue? Whaere can i go and look? Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you pass you server's ip as hostname to "grant" directive? I think it's not what you want. User's hostname is his real ip address, not ip address of server. Use wildcard to allow connection from any host (but not localhost):

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO user-name@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '******';
```

Comment: What should be the password then? Identified by?

Comment: Yes, password goes after `IDENTIFIED BY`.